# $A_n$ is generated by 3-cycles given $n\geq 3$. Is this proof correct?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

The elements of $A_n$ is either of the form $(a,b,c,...)...$ or of the form $(a,b)(c,d)...$

In both cases, the element is a product of an even number of transpositions, not pairwise disjoint in the first case. I thought I would just show that any product of two transpositions is a product of two 3-cycles.

Consider the first case and let $\sigma = (v_1,v_2)(v_2,v_4)$ be one of the several products of two transpositions. Since $\sigma = (v_1,v_2,v_4) = (v_1,v_4,v_2)(v_1,v_4,v_2)$ showing that the product of two $\textit{not}$ disjoint transpositions is a product of two 3-cycles. Since the elements from the first case are all odd cycles, they can be expressed as a product of an even number of transpositions $\textit{not}$ pairwise disjoint. Thus the argument presented above could be done with all pairs of transpositions for the entire cycle.

Consider the second case and let $\sigma = (v_1,v_2)(v_3,v_4)$ again be one of the several products of two transpositions, this time disjoint. Clearly $\sigma = (v_1,v_3,v_2)(v_1,v_3,v_4)$, so I have shown that the product of two disjoint transpositions is a product of two 3-cycles. The elements from the second case are products of an even number of disjoint transpositions, so this second argument could be done for all those pairs.

This should cover all possible cases of elements in $A_n$ and thus it's generated by 3-cycles.

EDIT#1: Changed the argument to account for products of transpositions which are not disjoint.

Comment: You almost got it, but if for example $\;v_2=v_3\;$ , you're saying that $$(v_1, v_2)(v_2,v_4)=(v_1,v_2,v_2)(v_1,v_2,v_4)$$ which makes not much sense. Just take care of this limit cases.

Comment: Right, of course. I'll have a go and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ideas are fine, but some arguments don't seem to be necessary.

It is sufficient to prove that the product of $2$ transpositions can be written as a product of $3$-cycles, but it is not necessary to have a product of *two* $3$-cycles. In the first part, you could just write $\sigma = (v_1,v_2,v_4)$. The fact that $\sigma = (v_1,v_4,v_2)(v_1,v_4,v_2)$  is not necessary.

You have proved that $A_n \subseteq \langle 3\text{-cycles} \rangle $. To conclude the proof (i.e. to show the reverse inclusion $\supseteq$), you just have to notice that all the products of $3$-cycles belong to $A_n$.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't the second case require me to express them as products of two 3-cycles? I can simplify it in the way you said for the first case, but to me it seems the second case demands products of two 3-cycles, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I was only speaking about the first case. In the second one, you indeed need two $3$-cycles.

Comment: Ok great. I'll simplify it, thank you.