# Understanding why the hint will prove that $A_{5}$ is generated by $3$-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

The question I want to answer is:

**Show that $A_{5}$ is generated by $3$-cycles.**

And I got a hint that: it suffices to show that every product $(a b)(c d)$ of two transpositions is a product of $3$-cycles.

But I do not understand how the hint will prove the required, could anyone explain that for me please?

**EDIT: I am not asking about the proof, I am asking about why proving the hint proves the required.**

Comment: Can you show that every element of $A_5$ can be written as a product of (disjoint) transpositions?

Comment: I am not asking about the proof @DerekAllums ... I am asking why proving this hint is the proof of the required.

Comment: Well if every element is a product of transpositions (Derek's hint) and every product of transpositions is a product of 3-cycles (the original hint) then it follows that every element  of $A_5$ is a product of three-cycles. So Derek's answer provides the bridge between the hint and the full result, which is exactly what you were asking for, right? Of course my summary in this comment is a bit too simplistic (and false - the original hint didn't talk about any product of transpositions, but just products of two) but I think it does explain how Derek's comment does indeed answer your question

Comment: O wait, maybe your question is something else: 'why does proving the hint amount to proving the full statement'. The answer there is: it doesn't. The situtation is more like this. You want to travel to city A and don't know the route. Now someone gives you the hint: go to B first. This can be useful: maybe you can actually see B and hence easily find a way. Also once at B getting to A might be easier because it has a train station or whatever. But still you have to find a way to get to B and then a way to get from B to A.

Comment: Same here, you have to prove the hint AND find a proof of the full statement using the hint. So: two tasks, but they may still be easier than finding an independent proof. (At least the person who gave you the hint seems to think so)

Comment: I understand that. As @Vincent explains, I am giving you a hint to help you bridge the gap, i.e., exactly what you asked. That's why it was posted as a comment and not an answer. If you know every element is a product of disjoint transpositions, and you know every product of transpositions can be written as a product of 3-cycles, then what else do you know?

Comment: And this has been explained already well at [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647389/a-n-is-generated-by-3-cycles-given-n-geq-3-is-this-proof-correct?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DerekAllums I know by definition that each permutation of $A_{5}$ is even ... which means that it can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions but I do not know how to show that they are **disjoint** ....... could you please explain for me how to show that?

Comment: @DerekAllums Are you trying to say "every element of $A_5$ is a product of elements of the form $(ab)(cd)$"? That is not equivalent to "every element of $A_5$ is a product of disjoint transpositions," which is false - only the involutions (order two elements) of $A_5$ are products of disjoint transpositions. For example, any odd-length cycle like $(abc)$ is not a product of disjoint transpositions.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, thanks - disjointness is wrong, but removing that and my hint still works. The link provided by Dietrich above goes through the steps.