# Checking if this proof of $A_{5}$ is generated by $3$-cycles is a complete proof?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

The question I want to answer is:

Show that $A_{5}$ is generated by $3$-cycles.

Here is the solution I found online:

**EDIT:**

First: Showing that $(ab) = (1b)(1a)(1b).$

$L.H.S = (ab) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& \dots& a& \dots &b& \dots & n \\
1 & 2& \dots &b& \dots &a&\dots &n \\ \end{pmatrix}\quad \quad (1)$

Now, $R.H.S$ in terms of permutation notation is:

$R.H.S = (1b)(1a)(1b)$

$= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& \dots& a& \dots &b& \dots & n \\
b & 2& \dots &a& \dots &1&\dots &n \\ \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& \dots& a& \dots &b& \dots & n \\
a & 2& \dots &1& \dots &b&\dots &n \\ \end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& \dots& a& \dots &b& \dots & n \\
b & 2& \dots &a& \dots &1&\dots &n \\ \end{pmatrix}$\

$$ = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2& \dots& a& \dots &b& \dots & n \\
1 & 2& \dots &b& \dots &a&\dots &n \\ \end{pmatrix}\quad \quad (2)$$

Hence from $(1)$ and $2,$ we have that $L.H.S = R.H.S$.

Now starting the main required proof

Let $\sigma \in A_{5}$ be an arbitrary permutation. Since every permutation in $A_{5}$ is an even permutation i.e. consists of an even number of transpositions then $\sigma = \tau_{1} \circ \tau_{2} \circ \dots \circ \tau_{2m}$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\tau_{i}$ are all transpositions.

Let $\tau_{1} = (ab), \tau_{2} = (cd),$ then $\tau_{1} = (1b)(1a)(1b) $ and $\tau_{2} = (1d)(1c)(1d).$ And therefore $$\tau_{1} \circ \tau_{2} = (1b)(1a)(1b)(1d)(1c)(1d) = (1 a b)(1 d b)(1 d c) $$ Which is a product of $3$-cycles.

Now, Since $\sigma$ consists of an even number of transpositions, then it is the product of $3$-cycles i.e.it is generated by $3$-cycles and since $\sigma$ was arbitrary permutation of $A_{5},$ then $A_{5}$ is generated by $3$-cycles as required.

And here is a solution I was directed to by some members of this site [$A_n$ is generated by 3-cycles given $n\geq 3$. Is this proof correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647389/a-n-is-generated-by-3-cycles-given-n-geq-3-is-this-proof-correct?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**My question is:**

Is the first solution is **complete** (it does not distinguish between disjoint transpositions and not disjoint ones)?

In my opinion, the first solution is simpler and clearer.

Comment: I don't find the image very legible, so I can't answer.  Please use mathjax to transcribe it, rather than using only images and links in your question.

Comment: You can't know what an n-cycle is, or the product  cycles,  unless you compose non-disjoint transpositions or permutations into disjoint n-cycles.

Comment: Where did you find the first solution online? Please give a link.

Comment: @amWhy I do not know how to transcribe an image could you please do it for me this time **only** to teach me?

Comment: @amWhy so you are saying that the first solution is incorrect?

Comment: The link is not accessible for free @coffeemath

Comment: Early on you have $(ab)=(1b)(1a)(1b).$ Could you actually *do* that calculation in your post? I could not get that right side.

Comment: @coffeemath sure I will edit my post with that calculation

Comment: @amWhy sorry my mother tongue is not English .... I translated the word transcribe and I understand it now ..... I will edit my post and remove pictures within 1 hour ..... so sorry about that.

Comment: @MathIgnorance I think I see that computation now, provided $1,a,b$ are distinct. Still good to include it, and say whether 1,a,b distinct.

Comment: @coffeemath so you are saying the proof should differentiate between distinct and indistinct transposition? if so, it is not that much clear for me the idea used to do so in the link I gave in my question..... Could you please explain it to me in a simple way?

Comment: @coffeemath ok I will edit my post .... I am working now on that.

Comment: @amWhy I edited some of my post .... but the edit is awful .... could you please help me correct the cut permutation?

Comment: @amWhy I am still transcribing my post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115070/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-mathignorance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should distinguish the cases where the transpositions are not disjoint.

This is because if in the case that $b=d$, you will get
$$\tau_1\tau_2=(1ab)(1bb)(1dc).$$
where in this case $(1bb)=\iota$ which is not a $3$-cycle. So for this case, you have to write
$$\tau_1\tau_2=(1ab)(1bc).$$

Comment: What does $(1bb)$ mean? [It isn't a $3$-cycle...]

Comment: @coffeemath In fact $(1bb)$ is not a correct way to write a permutation also. What I want to point out is there is a need to distinguish the case where the two transpositions are not disjoint.

Comment: Could you please explain this cases for me in details ? I do not see how to show them.

Comment: @MathIgnorance As I mentioned, if $(ab)$ and $(cd)$ are not disjoint, they must share a letter. Assume the shared letter is $b$, then by direct calculation, $(ab)(cb)=(cab)$ which is a $3$-cycle. Or you may stick to your formula, then you will get $(ab)(cb)=(1ab)(1bc)$ which is a product of two $3$-cycles.

Comment: but you said there are case**s** not only one case that I should check. What do you mean by that?

Comment: What do you mean by $(1ab)$?

Comment: In fact, one more case will be both the transpositions are identical. But their product will be identity. If you insist to consider this case, you can write $(ab)(ab)=(1ab)(1ab)$ which is again a product of two $3$-cycles.

Comment: Typo: Should be $(ab)(ab)=\iota=(1ab)(1ab)(1ab)$.

Comment: I think your line before last was correct.

Comment: Can you please, if you liked my question, to vote me up as I am banned from questions now ?

Answer (score 1):

An even simpler solution. Let $x\in A_5$. Then $x=(i_1,j_1)...(i_{2n},j_{2n})$: product of even number of involutions. So it is enough to prove that every product $(a,b)(c,d)$ is a product of $3$-cyles. If
$\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$ are not disjoint, then the product $(a,b)(c,d)$ is a 3-cycle. So it is enough to consider the case when these sets are disjoint. Notice that $(1,4,2)(3,4,2)=(1,2)(3,4)$ (the first permutation in the product acts first). Conjugating by arbitrary element of $S_5$, we get that any product of two disjoint involutions $(a,b)(c,d)$ is a product of  two $3$-cycles (because conjugation preserves the cycle structure), as required.

Comment: I think this is exactly what is written above in my solution.

Comment: No it is not the same at all.

Comment: I think the idea is the same ? or maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I think the idea is different. Even though the idea that you need to multiply permutations is used here too.